# How to structure music genres within Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a list of music genres that I want to store in Firestore, however I'm not sure how to structure the database.

Each music genre such as "Indie Rock" or "Alternative Rock" has a main category, e.g. Rock. Each genre needs to have an ID and I need to be able to both retrieve the main category of each genre, and retrieve all the genres within a main category. How do I structure this?

I could do Collection (Genres) -> Document (Main Category) -> Objects (Genres within category)? But then I can't auto assign an id to each object...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a sub-collection of genres, to achieve this.  When you want to see all of the sub-genres for a particular genre, simply fetch all documents from the `subGenres` collection.

See how to [add / set documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document) and how to [retrieve them all](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection).  You may want to read [how to structure data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data).

```
var subGenreDoc = {
    displayName: 'Indie Rock',
    notes: 'Some more info about Indie Rock'
};

var subGenreId = 'indieRock';

// Create a document with an auto ID (recommended)
var newId = db.collection('genres').doc('rock').collection('subGenres'),add(subGenreDoc);

// Creates a document with a specified ID
var setId = db.collection('genres').doc('rock').collection('subGenres'),set(subGenreId, subGenreDoc);

// Get all documents in the rock / subGenres sub-collection
var mySubGenres = db.collection('genres').doc('rock').collection('subGenres').get()
```

Comment: Thank you! If I was to associate a user document with the subgenres "Indie Rock" and "Alternative Rock" how would I do that? Would I have an array of "Interests" listing the IDs of the subgenres?

Comment: That is certainly an option.  You can store a reference to another document as a filed in Firestore.  Just be aware about how you plan to query this later.  If you only want to get the interests, once you've selected a user, then this will work.  If you want to query users based on their interests, this is slightly more complicated and you'll need to look at maps vs arrays